# Fetching JSON objects based on key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch, key-value

This code does a great job of fetching and rendering everything within the JSON array, but what if I am interested in only listing the objects with a particular key-value (like gender)? Would that happen during the fetch or the render?

```js
const URL = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people";

const main = document.getElementById("main");
main.innerHTML = "<p>Loading...";

fetch(URL).then((response) => response.json()).then((people) => main.innerHTML = getListOfNames(people));

const getListOfNames = (people) => {
  const names = people.map((person) => `<li>${person.name} - ${person.gender} </li>`).join("\n");

  return `<ul>${names}</ul>`;
};
```

Comment: Is better on the fetch. Because you'll get only the data you'll use.

Comment: So I'm guessing if a JSON page has a ton of info in it, users will still see a bit of a pause while their browser renders it all, regardless if I filter the data on the fetch or after the 'const' statement, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal case would be using GraphQL so you only fetch the data fields you need based on your criteria, in this case, there is no difference between changing the getListOfNames function for just outputting a person when its person.gender matches your criteria or simply passing to it a filtered array of people after fetching them all

Answer (score 0):

You would have to configure the api endpoint to accept filters if you'd like to return filtered results. Otherwise, you'd filter on render.

With underscore you'd do _.where(response, {gender: 'male'})

Comment: yeah, i added...  .filter(person => person.gender === 'male')  ... before that .map statement and it worked fine. thanks!